# Make a column in Excel and get its auto width without starting Excel / saving the file

Tags: c#, .net, excel, windows, winforms

I wanna make an Excel sheet with some columns in it (with a different font / font size) and then get the size of the columns (that automatically fit) without starting Excel or saving the file.

For an example:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RMfq.png)

I want to be able to get this without having to start Excel, or save the sheet from C#, I want it in memory in the code. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a Nuget package called EPPlus. It is probably also possible using the Excel Interop but I prefer to use this package as it does not depend on Excel being installed.

You can build up a spreadsheet like this.

```
ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage(); //Has constructors that accept file path as string or Stream.

//For demo purposes create a dummy spreadsheet.
var worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
//Set a cell value
worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "This is some sample text...";
//Make the font bold
worksheet.Cells["A1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
//Autofit all the columns
worksheet.Cells[worksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

//Get the column width. This is not 0 based.
//You can then round this to 2 decimal places if you want to
double colAWidth = worksheet.Column(1).Width;
```

Does this help? Is this what you're after?

As per our comments you can use the Excel Interop to get the exact width as shown by Excel, but this has it's own drawbacks such as not supporting streams, so you will need to save and delete any files accordingly.

```
var xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\MySpreadsheet.xlsx");

var sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
var columnRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[1, 1];
var colWidth = (double)columnRange.ColumnWidth;
xlApp.Quit();
```

Comment: homie u the MVP! do u know how to change the font/font size/make it bold (because then it will be a different width) thanks again.

Comment: I just tested this, and it's not giving accurate widths?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include making the font bold. But yes I appear to be seeing very slightly different results in Excel too. Hmmm.

Comment: Looks like there was a legit reason for this. See this issue on GitHub https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/89

Comment: so i cant do anything about it? do i have to use Interop?

Comment: Well that's up to you. Depends how important the exact excel value is to your scenario. The Interop will return the same value as Excel, but you have to open and close the application in code, also you can't load from a Stream so you will need to handle saving and disposing any files. I have updated my anwser to include the interop.

Comment: so basically interop is a COM with Excel and the library works without Excel, so using another API. hmmmm. alright. thanks a lot bro, you saved the day.